# Why do the diagrams in $\Gamma[\Phi]$ differ from those in $\Phi\Gamma^{\rm int}_{\Phi}[\Phi]$ only by numerical prefactors?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, feynman-diagrams, 1pi-effective-action

Suppose $W$ is the generator of connected Feynman diagrams in $\Phi^4$ theory. We define 
$$\Gamma[\Phi]=W[j]-W_jJ,\tag{13.37}$$

where $$W_jJ=\int{dxW_j(x)j(x)}\tag{13.38}$$
and $$ \Phi\equiv\frac{\delta W[j]}{\delta j(x)}.\tag{13.39}$$

Now we define
$$\Gamma^{int}[\Phi] \equiv \Gamma[\Phi]-\frac{1}{2} \Phi iG_0^{-1}\Phi, \tag{13.51}$$
where $G_0$ is the bare propagator.

The claim is that the diagrams in  $\Gamma[\Phi]$differ from those in $\Phi\Gamma^{int}_{\Phi}[\Phi]$ only by numerical prefactors, where  $$\Gamma^{int}_{\Phi}[\Phi]=\frac{\delta \Gamma^{int}[\Phi]}{\delta \Phi(x)}\tag{13.41}$$

This is done in Kleinert's [Chapter 13: *Notes on formal perturbation theory*](http://users.physik.fu-berlin.de/~kleinert/b6/psfiles/Chapter-12-formprpt.pdf).

Why is this claim true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kleinert is observing below eq. (13.64) that the [Euler vector field](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&as_q=&as_epq=euler+vector+field)$^1$

$$ V~:=~\int \!d^Dx~\Phi(x)\frac{\delta}{\delta \Phi(x)}$$
counts$^2$ the number of $\Phi$-powers in each term of the effective action $\Gamma[\Phi]$. So e.g. $V[\Phi^n]~=~n\Phi^n$, and so forth.

--

$^1$Note that Kleinert is using [deWitt's condensed notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DeWitt_notation), cf. e.g. eq. (13.38).

$^2$ In the heat of the argument, Kleinert overlooks the quadratic free part $\Gamma_0=\Gamma[\Phi]-\Gamma^{\rm int}[\Phi]$, but that is anyway trivial to account for.

Comment: what you mean is if we expand $\Phi\Gamma^{int}_{\Phi}[\Phi]$ and $\Gamma[\Phi]$ in powers of $\Phi$ and then compare them we will arrive in the result?

Comment: I updated the answer.